# pubnub pushregistry

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0, pubnub

I am working on pubnub j2me sdk and want to implement push notification in j2me as there is no regular platform to automatically run the application as in iOS, so socket/datagram pushregistry (don't want sms pushregistry) is the only option to do this task.

But I don't know how to implement this for pubnub j2me?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reconsider SMS push registry as sockets/datagrams push doesn't exist for J2ME.

Comment: in theory it actually exists, but i havent seen anyone successfully implement it. I looked into pub-nub push for j2me a year ago, but abandoned it. An alternative is to use time based push registry, you may be able to use it to solve your problem.